# Interleukin 6 class cytokines

Tags: cell-biology, physiology, immunology, human-physiology

Wikipedia says:

> Leukemia inhibitory factor, or LIF, is an interleukin 6 class cytokine that affects cell growth by inhibiting differentiation.

So does this means that il6=LIF ? or does it implies that both il6 and LIF belong to some common class of cytokines?  If latter is true then what is the name of that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [interleukin wikipedia page for IL6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interleukin#Interleukin_6) :

> number of other cytokines may be grouped with IL6 on the basis of sequence    similarity.[21][22][23] These include granulocyte colony-stimulating factor (GCSF) and myelomonocytic growth factor (MGF)

from the [Leukemia inhibitory factor wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leukemia_inhibitory_factor):

> LIF derives its name from its ability to induce the terminal
>   differentiation of myeloid leukemic cells, thus preventing their
>   continued growth.

From this we can suggest that LIF is grouped with the IL6 because of its action on myeloid leukemic cells and specifically on their growth (MGF).